# What is stored in typeinfo (GNU C++, Android NDK, ARM)

Tags: ida, c++, android, arm

IDA annotates some items as: **`typeinfo` for `_classname_`**.

What is that `typeinfo`, is it the same as `type_info`?
What information may be extracted from it? (e.g. I'd like to know the object size or virtual function table size).

I am particularly interested in GNU C++ (G++) from Android NDK for ARM.

Answer (score 3):

These objects are indeed instances of the `type_info` class (or, more likely, one of its descendants). The structure of those classes is described in the [Itanium C++ ABI](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#rtti-layout). You can also inspect the [`rtti.h`](http://docs.libreoffice.org/bridges/html/rtti_8h_source.html) file from GCC.

For a trimmed-down, data-only representation of these classes, check my [Recon 2012 presentation](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=704) (start at slide 27 or so).

Answer (score 2):

To add [Igor Skochinsky's answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/4319/4398):

Given VFT address, you can print the mangled class name:

```
unsigned int* vmtaddr = *(int*)obj_addr;
DLOG("class name: _Z%s",((char***)vmtaddr)[-1][1]);
```

The class name may be decoded with `c++filt`.

(The `_Z` thing is not stored there, but required for `c++filt` to work.)

You can also print the inheritance chain (the trick is that typeinfo is also an object, and if it is a `__cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info`, against whose mangled name we `strcmp()`, there has been single inheritance and a pointer to the superclass typeinfo follows the pointer to name):

```
    char* classchain = strrealloccat(NULL, "_Z");
    char**ptypeinfo = ((char***)vmtaddr[-1]);
    for (; ptypeinfo ; ptypeinfo = !strcmp(((char***)ptypeinfo[0])[-1][1], "N10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE") ? (char**)ptypeinfo[2] : 0) {
        //DLOG("tinfo: %p",ptypeinfo);
        //DLOG("class: _Z%s   meta: _Z%s",ptypeinfo[1], ((char***)ptypeinfo[0])[-1][1]);
        //DLOG("meta : _Z%s",((char***)ptypeinfo[0])[-1][1]);
        classchain = strrealloccat(strrealloccat(classchain, ptypeinfo[1]), "  _Z");
    }
    DLOG("inheritance chain: %s",classchain);
    free(classchain);
```

where `strrealloccat()` is defined as:

```
char* strrealloccat(char* buffer0, char *addition)
{
    char* buffer = realloc(buffer0, (buffer0 ? strlen(buffer0) : 0) + strlen(addition) + sizeof(char));
    if (!buffer) {
    return buffer;
    }
    if(!buffer0) {
    *buffer = 0;
    }
    return strcat(buffer, addition);
}
```

`_Z4hopeN4this5helpsE`